# Checking if Sitecore Analytics is really working

Tags: sitecore-client

I am bit lost in trying to figure out how to opt out Sitecore Analytics for us to comply to `GDPR` thingy, and then come to doubt if Sitecore Analytics is really working on my Sitecore instance. If it doesn't then I don't need to do the opting out.

So here's what  I found out:

1. Upon checking `Sitecore.xDB config` (from `Website\App_Config\Include`), both `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` and `Xdb.Enabled` was set to `true` **BUT** is being overridden by the `SitecoreSettings` config. So in the end, `Xdb.Enabled` was set to `false` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` was set to `true`. I've seen it from `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`. Weird thing is (I said weird just because I still have no idea WHY) when looking at my `SitecoreSettings` config, there's no node for that kind of setting. Only a setting for my `LicenseFile`.Interesting...
2. There was no `xDB license` installed. Upon checking it on `Sitecore Controler Panel > Administration > Installed licenses`.
3. `Sitecore.Analytics` config is **NOT** disabled
4. We don't have `mongoDB`

I don't understand the difference between `xDB.Enabled` and `xDB.Tracking.Enabled`. So I've read the documentation regarding Analytics (hopefully the link won't go dead): [Disabling xd and xd tracking](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/disabling-xdb-and-xdb-tracking.html)

Okay, so it says:

> **When you set Xdb.Tracking.Enabled to true and have xDB disabled:**
>
> 1. Contacts cannot be identified immediately, and any data gathered from the contact is discarded at the end of the session.
> 2. You can use personalization rules for contact facets and segmentation.
> 3. IP Geolocation services are available.
> 4. Engagement plan processing occurs for the live session.
> 5. Contact repositories are available for the session, and outcomes that are triggered during the session are registered.

Okay based on my understanding (Please don't punish me if I'm wrong :/ ), everything about the visitor interactions will be saved **BUT** on session-based only, then it will be then save to `mongoDB` or `sql` if there's no `mongoDB` (?). So if that's that's the case, it still really does tracking on the site's visitors (`anonymous visitors` only on my case, because we don't have login feature for the `site visitors`, if my understanding is correct though)

So my question is: Is my investigation correct?

What I'm using is `Sitecore 8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your analysis, the simple answer is your xDB is disabled. You will only be able to use the tracking mechanism but it will not get added to the xDB databases.

The `Xdb.Enable` setting is like a global flag to whether executes pipelines to save the captured data of a contact, interaction into the xdb.

So, as long as you have `xDB.Enable` as false, the Sitecore analytics, experience profile will be disabled

Comment: Ah, so basically, leaving the xDB.Analytics to TRUE is truly nonsense? Hm, I wonder what could be the other use of that. Is it safe to say that I'm not breaking any GDPR rules because of that?

Comment: If you have only the xdb.tracking as enabled, it will allow you to use the personalization engine but no data will be saved to xdb. This means that you won’t be able to do reporting, sitecore won’t be able to match the contact as all data are discard at user session end

Comment: thank you for the clarification